# How to pass input to a script with Ansible?

Tags: bash, ansible

I want to pass input to my script with Ansible.

```yaml
- name: Transfer and execute a script.
  hosts: all
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "portale"   
      prompt: "Seleziona il portale?\n1- portal\n2- portal2\n"
      private: no

  tasks:
     - name: Copy and Execute the script
       script: /home/ansible/scripts/test.sh arg1
       args:
         responses: "{{ portale }}"
```

I have change shell to command, but nothing. `test.sh` as one input.

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Can you elaborate more what is the problem or the question here?

Answer (score 0):

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars_prompt:

  - name: "PORTAL"
    prompt: "Seleziona il portale?\nPortal 1: [1]\nPortal 2: [2]\n"
    private: no

  tasks:

  - name: Execute
    shell:
      cmd: "echo {{ PORTAL }}"
    register: output

  - debug:
      var: output
```

executed via

```bash
ansible-playbook main.yml --check -v
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
Seleziona il portale?
Portal 1: [1]
Portal 2: [2]
: 1

TASK [debug] ****************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  output:
    changed: true
    cmd: echo 1
    delta: null
    end: null
    failed: false
    msg: Command would have run if not in check mode
    rc: 0
    skipped: true
    start: null
    stderr: ''
    stderr_lines: []
    stdout: ''
    stdout_lines: []
```

The same approach, referencing the portal choosed within the command line will work for [`script` module – Runs a local script on a remote node after transferring it](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/script_module.html) too.